# Reporting services Data Source to Oracle

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

We have set up Data Source to Oracle on our SSRS 2008 reporting manager as simply:

> Data Source: Oracle (from drop down list) Connection string: Data
>   Source=SERVERNAME;Unicode=True

And it all works fine until something happens - we assumed after windows updates.

This connection doesn't work. The error is:

> "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw
>   BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64
>   bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."

We do have 32bit Oracle driver on this server. I don't know if there is a 64bit one already.

Then we have created another one to ORacle but is ODBC:

> Data Source: ODBC (from drop down list) Connection string:
>   DSN=SERVERNAME;

After this one is tested for connection (with the button in the properties window) the first one starts working.

And then we continue with the Oracle Data Source as usual and until the next failure. It happened couple of times so far and the solution is just to open the ODBC connection, hit "Test Connection", that works fine. Then go back to Oracle data source and that one works.

It is very unreliable to operate reporting service for the users and also annoying for staff as we don't have a solution.

Any ideas for what we might be looking on that server to have it working 100% of time?

Answer (score 0):

You are running your SSIS package in 64 bit mode but attempting to access a 32 bit driver.

Either (a) [switch to 32 bit mode](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/swtich-package-from-64bit-to-32bit.html) or (b) uninstall your 32 bit driver and install the 64 bit one. You really do not want both 32 and 64 bit on the same server :-)

As to why it is happening infrequently? Hard to tell because there is insufficient information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your windows is is 64 bit, and oracle client is 32 bit, 
install both clients (32 and 64 bit) in separate folder path with same tnsname file and restart SQL Server Reporting Server service. It get solved for me.